# backup Magento store

Tags: database, backup, magento-1.4

How I can create a full backup of the store without ftp/ssh or cPanel access? I have access only in Magento admin. The version of Magento store is 1.4.

[image]

**Update:** I try to install a [new extension](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/magebackup-backup-solution-lite.html) but I have this error:

No releases for package "magento-community/MageBackup_MageBackupFree" exist
PEAR ERROR: install failed

Comment: You're probably going to need FTP or SSH access. Is there a reason that you can't get it?

Comment: for this reason I ask here, because I can't access that ftp or ssh, I have access only with magento administrator user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to **System > Tools > backups**, then you create any kind of backup like

1)System Backup

2)Database Backup

3)Database & media Backup

once you click on "Roll back" it will revert backup to old state.

if the backup file didn't create under var folder means, may be its permission issue.

Comment: thank you for your answer but magento 1.4 have only db backup, I edit my post and I add a image to see this.

Comment: Go to System > Config > Advanced > System > Scheduled Backup Settings and you can choose the type from there.

Comment: no I don't have  Scheduled Backup Settings in the  System > Config > Advanced > System section

Comment: OK, maybe it wasn't there in v1.4 (I'm afraid I have no way of checking)

Comment: or exist another module / extension that allow me to see or download all files?

Answer (score 0):

Magento is enough secure , but there are always unexpected moments when your Magento 2 store could break.

**For instance**,

- A server crash, exploits, hacking, bugs and other mistakes.
- Tackling is issue to need know how to create Backup.
- You can check for this link ["How to Create Backups for Magento 2 store"](https://www.envisionecommerce.com/how-to-create-backups-for-your-magento-2-store/).

Hope this will beneficial for you!!